# Kiel traduki la anglan vortgrupon, "big game hunter"?

Tags: phrase-requests

La angla esprimo "big game hunter" signifas ĉasiston kiu mortpafadas grandajn sovaĝajn bestojn, ekzemple en Afrikaj landoj.

Mi uzis la kunmetitan vorton "sovaĝbestĉasisto", sed ĝi aspektas al mi iomete tro longa kaj malbela.

Ĉu iu povas eltrovi pli bonan alternativon?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to make a single word out of it. I checked a couple of languages and they also had to spell out the concept, just as English does.

I think this could do it:

```
ĉasisto de grandaj bestoj
```

Answer (score 0):

Vi probable devas ĉiuokaze difini pri kio temas en la komenco de via artikolo.

> Pluraj ĉasistoj alvenas ĉiujare al… por ĉasi grandajn [ĉasaĵojn](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%89asa%C4%B5o), ekz.  alkojn kaj cervojn.

Poste sufiĉas, ke vi uzas nur la vorton ĉasisto.